# Sort list into multiple lists based on its values

Tags: java

I have a list and I need to sort it in ascending/descending based on its sequence.
For e.g. I start with the first index and create a sublist until values are in either ascending/descending order. If the order changed then start creating a new sublist.

Input

```
List<Integer> = [1,2,3,4,8,7,5,6]
```

Output

```
List<List<Integer>> = [[1,2,3,4,8], [8,7,5], [5,6]]
```

Input

```
List<Integer> = [8,7,8,9]
```

Output

```
List<List<Integer>> = [[8,7], [7,8,9]]
```

Input

```
List<Integer> = [1,2,2,1]
```

Output

```
List<List<Integer>> = [[1,2], [2,2], [2,1]]
```

Comment: Please edit your question to share the code you've written so far in attempt to solve this problem, and point out the part that isn't working or that you're stuck on,

Comment: ```[1,2,2,1]```  => ```[1,2,2],[1]``` or ```[1,2][2,1]``` or ```[1,2][2,2][2,1]```?

Comment: @zysaaa [1,2][2,2][2,1]

Comment: Edit your question and add your attempt in solving this and explain where you are stuck. SO is not a code writing service for your needs/requirements

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that may help. Explanations have been added as comments at important places.

The crucial component is the simple `enum Direction`. I have assumed "equals" also apart from "ascending" and "descending". If that is not required, then include the equals check in `Direction.ASC` or `Direction.DESC` depending upon your choice.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiPredicate;

public class SortedSubLists{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        List<List<Integer>> testData = Arrays.asList( 
            Arrays.asList( 1,2,3,4,8,7,5,6 ),
            Arrays.asList( 8,7,8,9 ),
            Arrays.asList( 1,2,2,1 )
        );
        
        for( List<Integer> input : testData ) {
            List<List<Integer>> subLists = split( input );
            
            System.out.println( "\r\nInput: " + input );
            for( List<Integer> l : subLists ) System.out.println( l );
        }
    }

    /** Represents the direction of the movement of data */
    private static enum Direction {
        ASC(( prev, curr ) -> prev - curr < 0), DESC(( prev, curr ) -> prev - curr > 0), EQ(( prev, curr ) -> prev - curr == 0);

        private Direction( BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> applicability ){
            this.applicability = applicability;
        }

        private BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> applicability;

        static Direction get( Integer prev, Integer curr ){
            for( Direction d : values() ){
                if( d.applicability.test( prev, curr ) ) return d;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> split( List<Integer> list ){
        Direction dir = null;
        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        Integer prev = null;
        List<Integer> currList = null;
        for( Integer i : list ){
            /* For the first element in the input, create a sub-list here and add the first element. */
            if( prev == null ) {
                currList = newList( result );
                currList.add( i );
            }
            else{
                /* Find the direction. If it has changed, create a new sub-list. Otherwise, continue with the
                 * existing one. */
                Direction newDir = Direction.get( prev, i );
                if( dir == null ) dir = newDir;
                else{
                    if( dir != newDir ) {
                        dir = newDir;
                        currList = newList( result );
                        currList.add( prev );
                    }
                }

                currList.add( i );
            }
            
            prev = i;

        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<Integer> newList( List<List<Integer>> result ){
        List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        result.add( newList );
        return newList;
    }
}
```

Output from running the program

```
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
[8, 7, 5]
[5, 6]

Input: [8, 7, 8, 9]
[8, 7]
[7, 8, 9]

Input: [1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 2]
[2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<List<T>> sortedSubList(List<T> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    List<List<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int start = 0;
    if (size >= 2) {
        int prev = list.get(0).compareTo(list.get(1));
        for (int i = 1, max = size - 1; i < max; ++i) {
            int next = list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1));
            if (prev != next) {
                result.add(list.subList(start, i + 1));
                start = i;
            }
            prev = next;
        }
    }
    result.add(list.subList(start, size));
    return result;
}
```

and

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> void test(List<T> list) {
    System.out.println(list + " -> " + sortedSubList(list));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    test(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 5, 6));
    test(List.of(8, 7, 8, 9));
    test(List.of(1, 2, 2, 1));
    test(List.of(1, 2));
    test(List.of(1));
    test(List.of());
    test(List.of("a", "b", "b", "a"));
}
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 5, 6] -> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 8], [8, 7, 5], [5, 6]]
[8, 7, 8, 9] -> [[8, 7], [7, 8, 9]]
[1, 2, 2, 1] -> [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 1]]
[1, 2] -> [[1, 2]]
[1] -> [[1]]
[] -> [[]]
[a, b, b, a] -> [[a, b], [b, b], [b, a]]
```